# how to set host name and scheme for a custom header - url scheme

Tags: android, url-scheme

I have a simple page on the server side like below link :

```
<button onclick="location.href='http://www.example.com/com.example.example://?status=true'">click me</button>
```

now I would like when I click on `click me` button, my application opens.

but how should I set the `data` tag in manifest.xml ?

---

```
        <intent-filter >
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <data android:host="http://www.example.com" android:scheme="com.example.example"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
```

---

**updated :**

```
        <intent-filter >
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <data android:path="/com.example.example" android:scheme="http" android:host="www.example.com" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
```

after click on `click me`,Nothing happens.

---

**updated**

```
        <intent-filter >
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <data android:path="/com.shadyab.shadyab" android:scheme="http" android:host="www.shadyab.com" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

`scheme` is `http` and `host` is `www.example.com`, I don't know why you. after the host comes the `path` . You can use one between

```
  android:path="string"
  android:pathPattern="string"
  android:pathPrefix="string"
```

Comment: I want when user leave to http ://www.example.com/com.example.example://?status=true address my app will open.

Comment: do you mean click ? probably setting  `android:path="/com.example.example"`, `android:scheme="http"` and `android:host="www.example.com"` is enough

Comment: yes, but it not works fine :( => android:path="/com.example.example", android:scheme="http" and android:host="www.example.com"

Comment: can you update your question with the changes you made and what's happenin

Comment: I assume that html page runs on the browser of the device where you have the application installed

Comment: yes, my html page runs on the browser of the device, this page is for test . I run my browser on device .

Comment: And the url you declared matches what you have in the onclick property in the html page?

Comment: can you try  `android:pathPrefix="/com.shadyab.shadyab/"` instead of path?

Comment: I am clueless sorry. It worked for me this way. The only difference is that I am getting a link on Gmail. What you could try is to have a simple  link in the first place and go ahead step by step